# Segmentation fault when running ccall using Threads.@threads

Tags: multithreading, julia

I am using ccall from Julia (1.2.0) to call a c function that I have created in a loop that runs in multiple cores:

```
Threads.@threads for i in 1:10   
       ccall((:myfunction, "myclib", (...), input[i])
end
```

This implementation runs fine without Threads.@threads but crashes due to segmentation fault when I use Threads.@threads and I have no idea why. I checked all the c functions that I am using in myclib and they are all thread safe.

My question is the following: In this kind of implementations, are the functions that run on c thread independent or they are linked somehow? For example, do they share global variables? Or does the stack memory limit apply to each thread independently or to the memory used by all threads?

Thanks for your help,

Dylan

Comment: Sometimes the C library itself is not thread safe. For example, some shared resource within the library itself might be released by one thread before another thread is finished with the resource.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by removing all the global variables of myfunction in c. However, I don't really understand how the global variables work when with a c function is called using ccall with multi threads.

Comment: I would read up on multithreaded programs in C alone. The safe practices with global and static variables that such documents teach would apply also to C library calls from Julia.